# convert ul li to select option - wordpress

Tags: php, html, type-conversion

i need to convert this code to a select option for selecting categories in wordpress instead of showing icons.

```
<div class="form-main-section classiera-post-cat">
<div class="classiera-post-main-cat">
    <h4 class="classiera-post-inner-heading">
    <?php esc_html_e('Select an Occasion', 'classiera') ?> :
    </h4>

    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <?php 
        $categories = get_terms('category', array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'parent' => 0,
                'order'=> 'ASC'
            )   
        );

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            //print_r($category);

    </ul><!--list-unstyled-->
    <input class="classiera-main-cat-field" name="classiera-main-cat-field" type="hidden" value="">
</div><!--classiera-post-main-cat-->
<div class="classiera-post-sub-cat">
    <h4 class="classiera-post-inner-heading">
    <?php esc_html_e('Select a Category', 'classiera') ?> :
    </h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled classieraSubReturn">
    </ul>
    <input class="classiera-sub-cat-field" name="classiera-sub-cat-field" type="hidden" value="">
    </div><!--classiera-post-sub-cat-->
    <!--ThirdLevel-->
    <div class="classiera_third_level_cat">
        <h4 class="classiera-post-inner-heading">
        <?php esc_html_e('Select a Category', 'classiera') ?> :
        </h4>
        <ul class="list-unstyled classieraSubthird">
        </ul>
        <input class="classiera_third_cat" name="classiera_third_cat" type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
    <!--ThirdLevel-->
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't need to have all the icons set to each category, just the name of the categories.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Take the [tour] and read the [ask] guide, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, rather than giving a specification for what you need.

Comment: As well as reading the above links, please familiarise yourself with what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

0,
                'parent' => 0,
                'order'=> 'ASC'
            )   
        );

?>

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {?>
```

___value you need to store___"?>>name __name you want to display__?>
            //print_r($category);

Comment: ignore the above text cause i am not able to write what and how i want

Comment: <?php

        $categories = get_terms('category', array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'parent' => 0,
                'order'=> 'ASC'
            )   
        );

?>

<select class="list-unstyled list-inline">
   

 <?php

        foreach ($categories as $category) {?>
<option value="<? echo category-> ___value you need to store___"?>><? echo category->name __name you want to display__?></option>
            //print_r($category);
 
 <?}?>   </select><!--list-unstyled-->

Comment: This is way u can achieve what u are opting for

Comment: I tried to add the code you suggested but it didn't work :(

Comment: give me more details i will try to write